# БД в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, база-данных

Скажите мне нужно сделать такую таблицу в Visual Studio(локальную) для каждого пользователя программы своя БД на компе, вот такого вида

[Тык](http://s017.radikal.ru/i443/1111/e2/c320eb4ec9f1.png)

Но вот беда, я её сделал и она работает, **НО** после перезапуска компьютера она становится пустой.... Может быть есть другие способы сделать такую БД?

Comment: а с чего бы ей пустой становиться?

Comment: Не знаю, просто поле перезапуска компьютера, база пустая. Или это у меня так, можете протестировать прогу?

Comment: т.е. неоднократные перезапуски проги на базу так не влияют, а reset полностью очищает?

Comment: http://rghost.ru/32266041 - попробуйте. Может быть это только у меня такой баг... всякое может быть.

Comment: ужас, вам самим удобно вводить данные в таблицу? если да, то для других людей сделайте это удобнее

Comment: Ну я не умею делать так чтобы ID сам увеличивался, и дата сама вводилась(это же не phpMyAdmin), а все остальное вроде удобно.

Comment: автоинкремент Id делается в конструкторе таблицы: 
``свойства столбца`` -> ``спецификация идентификатора`` -> ``да``
автоматический ввод даты:
``свойства столбца`` -> ``значение по умолчанию`` -> ``newDate()``

Comment: Спасибо большое! А что насчет исчезновение данных в таблице?

Ну вы программку не удаляйте, завтра если вспомните запустите(только щяс внесите какие-нибудь данные)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вносить записи в базу данных в твоем случае лучше использовать SQLite или Access

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще использовать SQL Server Compact.